# Pages throwing 404 error on server load

Tags: taxonomy, 404-error, routing

I have a really strange problem. I have to fix a strange bug in a wordpress installation that is related to the server load.

When the site receive more than 5 parallel request some pages starts to throw 404 errors. The pages throwing the errors are never the same and seems to be totally random.

I can recreate the problem on my local machine using curl in the terminal :

```
$ curl -I http://site.local.com/path/to/page & curl -I http://site.local.com/path/to/page/ & curl -I http://site.local.com/path/to/page/ & curl -I http://site.local.com/path/to/page/ & curl -I

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:31:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.11 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
X-Pingback: http://site.local.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:31:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.11 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
X-Pingback: http://site.local.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:31:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.11 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
X-Pingback: http://site.local.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:31:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.11 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
X-Pingback: http://site.local.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The second curl call return a 404 errors.

I have disabled all the plugins and this behavior is still happening.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does it also happen when using a standard theme such as twentyfourteen?

Comment: Does not happen with the standard theme. The theme the project is using is the "Stand" theme. Do you know any files I should be profiling to point point the issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the theme, so I cannot be specific. My guess would be there's some poorly designed database interaction built into the theme, that is causing the crashing. Try contacting the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

This theme flush the rewrite rules on *every request*. I have removed the multiple calls to flush_rewrite_rules() and the problem is now gone.